# Can a virus, a skilled user, or a privileged app modify the Javascript in my Cordova hybrid app that is already installed on a user's Android or iOS?

Tags: javascript, cordova, security, eval, code-injection

I'm wondering about Cordova's security for app building. So after the app is installed on a user's device, can an adversary or another app/virus with root privileges modify the HTML and/or Javascript sources which are stored in the WWW folder of my Cordova app?

I know I should not use eval in my Cordova app, but if adversaries can modify Javascript, they can inflict the same damage which eval does.

I am worried about a scenario like the following:

1. The user installs the app.
2. An adversary has the phone for a few minutes or time long enough to change the Javascript in a way that can expose or send run-time information like global variables.
3. The attacker adds Javascript code which sends session keys to a domain or to an email. Or, if domain whitelisting is properly used, the attacker just stores them in a persistent storage which the s/he can later retrieve.

Is this a realistic concern?

Comment: As a general rule, don't store anything sensitive on the client-side

Comment: If the device is already compromised with malicious software that can cross process boundaries, *nothing you can do* will be secure. It's up to the user to make sure they're rootkit-free.

Comment: `As a general rule, don't store anything sensitive on the client-side`
^ This +10000

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I agree. But... even if I don't store sensitive information, if the attacker modifies my Javascript, they can add code to intercept my app's login page and send the password to themselves even if I don't ever store  the password in my app's local storage in plain format. If I'm not mistaken, it is common practice to store a hashed password which then can be compared with the hash of user's entered password. A modified javascript can intercept the password before it's hashed/compared.

Comment: If there is malicious software on the device, pretty much all bets are off.. You're at the mercy of the problematic software. You could have incremental checks for code consistency if you're really concerned, like a SVN comparison.

Comment: I think it'd require a jailbroken device, and even then it'd be difficult because of code signing, but yeah theoretically it is possible. I mean think of it this way, even if you 100% secure your app (impossible), I could deploy a malicious JavaScript engine that intercepts the password and does something with it. In practice, your statement of "for a few minutes" is what makes this unfeasible. If I had it for a few hours, and also already developed the tools to inject my code targeted to your app, you could be in trouble.

Comment: @Pogrindis good idea, except the malicious code could circumvent the code consistency checks to always returns "everything is OK" :)

Comment: @dman2306 Those checks would be compiled as opposed to scripted. Which again like you say can be circumvented, but would need to be specifically targeted that proc/

Comment: @dman2306 So based on what you're saying, Cordova does not store the Javascript & HTML in a place accessible or writable by the normal user? Which means that elevated privileges are required.
So where/how does Cordova store the HTML and Javascript anyway?

Comment: @abbood99 Where it is stored will depend on the OS, but no, applications on iOS and Android do not have access to the files of other applications, they are sandboxed. You'd need a rooted phone to do this. Of course I add the caveat of there could be a bug in iOS and Android that let's people circumvent the sandboxing so it's not 100%

Comment: To those who marked the question as too broad: A yes-no question, by definition, cannot be too broad!